# Uso correto do DOM com react.js

Tags: javascript, react

Sabendo que o ReactJS usa um DOM virtual onde os elementos são processados em uma representação do DOM na memória para que todas as alterações sejam feitas de forma mais rápida então seria "errado" usar findDOMNode para acessar diretamente um elemento do DOM e manipular seu estado?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim, seria errado.

`findDOMNode` só existe para leitura de informações do DOM (ex: posição, valor de campos do formulário, etc). Modificar o `DOM` diretamente também pode gerar inconsistências, porque a visão que o `framework` tem do `DOM (virtual-dom)` não sera a mesma do `DOM` no browser, então ele pode acabar sobrescrevendo os valores que você setou manualmente.

Comment: Então só para ficar mais claro, com relação a pegar o valor de um input text a forma mais correta seria o findDOMNode? Pois os primeiros testes que andei fazendo com o react eu estava fazendo uma gambiarra maior do mundo com eventos para não acessar o DOM diretamente.

Comment: Boa surpresa ver-te por aqui @fabiomcosta!